# How to restrict scope of set_fact variable in ansible

Tags: ansible

below is my ansible playbook for validation of objects - I am first using validateip role and under that executing login,validation and then logout tasks.

```yaml
- name: validate  object
  vars:
   mserver: [1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2]
   domain: [3.3.3.3,4.4.4.4]
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: validateip
      when: object_type == "ip"
  with_together:
           - "{{ mserver_hostname }}"
           - "{{ domain }}"


- name: Checking Network objects
      uri:
        url: "https://{{item.0}}/web_api/show-objects"
        validate_certs: False
        method: POST
        headers:
          x-chkp-sid: "{{ login.json.sid }}"
        body:
          type: host
          filter: "{{ip}}"
          ip-only: true
        body_format: json
      register: check_host_result
      when: item.0 != ""

    - debug:
        var: check_host_result
    - name: Checking if Network Object exists
      set_fact:
        item_ip_exists: true
        obj_name: "{{ item2['name'] }}"
      loop: "{{ check_host_result.json.objects  }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item2
      when:
        - item2['ipv4-address'] is defined and item2['ipv4-address'] == ip

    - debug:
        msg: "Network Object exists with name [{{obj_name}}]"
      when: item_ip_exists is defined
    - debug:
        msg: " Network Object ({{ip}}) will be created"
      when: item_ip_exists is not defined
```

I am facing issue  for set_fact variable  like obj_name  and item_ip_exists 
so when loop runs on  first item and if object is present so it set both the variable  (obj_name  and item_ip_exists ) and print the correct debug messages.
but when 2nd item executed and there if object is not present so it is printing the wrong debug message due to the set_fact variables( obj_name and item_ip_exists) which has already the value from the first items execution
so how i can restrict the scope of set_fact variables ( obj_name and item_ip_exists ) so when second item execute the variables take the value from there not from previously set_fact values.
I am totally stuck here.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please edit your question, have a look at the formatting aids on top of the editor window and on the right column, and format your question correctly more specifically the code blocks so that they are readable. The preview below the editor updates live so you can check the result of your changes before you publish.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62390505/edit) and fix the formatting, and while there, try and focus your question via an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck

Comment: Thanks  Zeitounator  and mdanie for looking at my question.  AS asked  i have formatted my code properly. Please help me.

Comment: Hey Guyes any help on it, how I can solve this issue or other approach to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, the variable that is set by `set_fact` stays defined (for the same host) and keeps the value that had been assigned on the previous loop's pass.

As a solution (which is pretty ugly, to be frank) you may want to *redefine* the variable's value in the very beginning of the loop and set it to `None` by something like this:

```
- set_fact:
    my_variable:
```

Then you'll have to check if it's equal or unequal to `None`. Alas, no one could *undefine* a previously defined variable in Ansible, that's why your condition won't be `my_variable is undefined`, but will be `my_variable | default(None) == None`.

Ugly, right.